# Nokogiri Use Ruby-Core Method as XML Node Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

How do I get Nokogiri to accept a ruby-core method as a node name e.g.

`xml.hash Digest::SHA256.file form.survey_xml`  should return something like this

`<hash>cde6f0dd030aac1d3aa6d231b7c0cc30a34686a6f6780c468ccc64a4822f01e0</hash>`

Instead I am getting an error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in hash` of course because hash is a ruby method.

How do I set the node name to `hash` using the Nokogiri DSL since the API I am interacting with expects that node.

I can just create the xml manually but the answer I am looking for is specifically using nokogiri

More Info

Here is the xml I am trying to create:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
  <xforms xmlns=\"http://openrosa.org/xforms/xformsList\">
    <xform>
      <formID>1</formID>
      <name>BLAH BLAH</name>
      <version>1</version>
      <hash>892734982SDHFK238479823749234934</hash> 
  <downloadUrl>/Users/me/workspace/dashboard/public/uploads/survey_xml/survey_xml/2/S_1_.xml</downloadUrl>
  </xform>
</xforms>
```

Here is my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'digest'

def mine
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new{ |xml|
    xml.xforms xmlns: 'http://openrosa.org/xforms/xformsList' do 
      @forms.each do |form|
        xml.xform do 
          xml.formID form.id
          xml.name form.name
          xml.version 1
          xml.hash Digest::SHA256.file form.survey_xml.survey_xml.file.file
          xml.downloadUrl form.survey_xml.survey_xml.file.file
       end
      end
    end
}.to_xml
end
```

Based on **dimakura's** answer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other Nokogiri methods.

**xpath**:

```
node.xpath('hash').first
```

**search**:

```
node.search('hash').first
```

**children**:

```
xml.children.select{|x| x.name == 'hash'}
```

If you are creating new elements, not getting them. Then you can add them, for example, like this:

```
xml.add_child '<hash>hash-code</hash>'
```

**Update** When working with `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` special names should be used with underscore (`_`):

```
xml.hash_ 'your-hash'
```

Comment: when I do xml.add_child I get a totally different format from what I wanted. I have included  code and what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Mutuma you should use `xml.hash_`. see updated answer